Sharing Auth session between two Laravel apps on separate servers
I have a requirement (if possible) where I have to share Auth sessions between two Laravel applications deployed on different servers, having different DBs, and different subdomains, and the only thing they will share is the same base domain i.e. xyz.mydomain.com and abc.mydomain.com
Scenario Example:
APP1:
url: xyz.mydomain.com
server: Azure1
db: xyz_db
APP2:
url: abc.mydomain.com
server: Azure2
db: abc_db
Now I want to understand, if there is a way I can possibly achieve this, i.e. share Auth session between two totally separate applications, where there is also a possibility that a user who is present in one database will not surely be in other database as well, as both applications have their own db.
Any lead or help would be much appreciated, thanks.
I'm not really sure if something like this can be done or not. Because logically this seems off. But I still want to get some expert opinions on this

I think at least the users table needs to be shared from the two systems. Or you would have to implement you own custom auth that attempts to authenticate on both databases

@krisgjika Yes I am also somewhat of the same opinion that both systems should have the same database and be deployed on the same servers to achieve something like that. The reason I am asking here is to be sure about it.

they don't need to have the same DB, they just need to share the users and sessions. So the User model would have the same connection in both systems. Also sessions would share the same database driver connection, or some shared resource
